# "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory. (errno=12)"

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

I'm using putty to connect VM. There I have installed java8 and tomcat8. While trying to run the application using tomcat as aremote server getting 404 error.

So I have restarted tomcat. While stopping the server I'm getting this error. Can anyone know the solution for this?

Answer (score 10):

**Failed to reserve shared memory** message may appear when JVM failed to allocate huge pages for Java heap from shared memory. This may happen only when `-XX:+UseLargePages` is on.

**errno=12** means "Out of memory".

The explanation from [HotSpot sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/aa4ffb1f30c9/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#l3582):

```
// Possible reasons for shmget failure:
// 1. shmmax is too small for Java heap.
//    > check shmmax value: cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
//    > increase shmmax value: echo "0xffffffff" > /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
// 2. not enough large page memory.
//    > check available large pages: cat /proc/meminfo
//    > increase amount of large pages:
//          echo new_value > /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
//      Note 1: different Linux may use different name for this property,
//            e.g. on Redhat AS-3 it is "hugetlb_pool".
//      Note 2: it's possible there's enough physical memory available but
//            they are so fragmented after a long run that they can't
//            coalesce into large pages. Try to reserve large pages when
//            the system is still "fresh".
```

Follow the instructions above or just remove `-XX:+UseLargePages` JVM option.