# Facing issues in Solr 8.11.1 version, solr is not starting up

Tags: linux, server, solr

Getting the below mentioned error on putty while starting up the Solr:

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory.
(error = 1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968433/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning-failed-to-reserve-shared-memory-er